# How To Mock A HttpClient By Wraping HttpClient In A Interface

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I would like to use Moq to mock my HttpClient calls. I would like to do this by using an Interface to wrap the HttpClient. My Interface:

```
public interface IMyHttpClient
{
    Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(string url);
}
```

And my class:

```
 public class MyHttpClient : IMyHttpClient
 {
    private HttpClient http;
    public MyHttpClient(HttpClient _http)
    {
        http = _http;
    }
    public Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        return http.GetFromJsonAsync<T>(url);
    }
}
```

FYI: Just showing the one method.

My test is:

```
 var myObj = new MyObj();
 Mock moc = new Mock<IMyHttpClient>().Setup(a => a.GetJsonAsync<MyObj> 
 ("url")).Returns(Task.FromResult(myObj));
```

I am getting a compiler error:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 
'Moq.Language.Flow.NonVoidSetupPhrase`2[IMyHttpClient,
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[MyObject]]' to type 'Moq.Mock'.
```

I do not understand where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Consider using `NSubstitute` - it allows setup mocks exactly the same way you work with  real objects. Your example will look like `httpClientMock.GetJsonAsync<MyObj>("url").Returns(myObj)`

Comment: Alternative approach not to mock `HttpClient`, but extract it usage out of business logic, then it can be tested against actual collaborators without mocking. Testing actual implementation will provide more valuable feedback than using mocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Returns()` does not return a `Mock` as the error indicates. Separate the declaration and the setup:

```
var myObj = new MyObj();
Mock<IMyHttpClient> moc = new Mock<IMyHttpClient>();
moc.Setup(a => a.GetJsonAsync<MyObj>("url"))
    .ReturnsAsync(myObj);
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of the mocking framework.

Comment: Eternally grateful!